# Computing Triple Integral Using Spherical Coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, spherical-coordinates

I just have trouble finding the bounds for $\phi$ in this problem. So far I found $\pi < \theta < 3\pi/2$ and  $0 < \rho < \sqrt{10}$

Use spherical coordinates to calculate the triple integral of $f(x,y,z) = y$ over the region $$x^2+y^2+z^2= 10$$ and  $$x,y,z ≤ 0$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Hi, p is rho. My apology for the notation confusion.

Comment: @MathCoolGuy99 $\dfrac{\pi}{2}\leq\phi\leq\pi$.

Comment: Oh yes, I apologise. You are indeed correct. I have since deleted my erroneous comment.

Comment: @Nosrati, I got it solved on my own! Thank you so much!

Comment: @MathCoolGuy99, you can post your solution as an answer to this question. It may help future users

Answer (score 2):

At the moment I am trying to give an answer to this old question, but I am not entirely sure.
The discussion in the comments mentions boundaries $\pi/2\leq\varphi\leq\pi$ and $\pi\leq\theta\leq \frac32\pi$ which I do not understand.

Can you enlighten me, or spot my mistake? Thanks in advance. (I will of course edit, or delete my answer if necessary)

$\rho=\sqrt{10}$

We get:

$$\int_{\pi}^{\frac32\pi}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{10}} \rho\sin(\varphi)\sin(\theta)\cdot\rho^2\sin(\varphi)\,d\rho\,d\varphi\,d\theta$$

Using the formula for cylindrical coordinates

$$\iiint_B f(\rho,\theta,\varphi)\cdot \rho^2\sin(\varphi)\,d\rho\,d\varphi\,d\theta$$

And the change of coordinates:

$x=\rho\sin(\varphi)\cos(\theta)$

$y=\rho\sin(\varphi)\sin(\theta)$

$z=\rho\cos(\varphi)$

Which then evaluates to $$-\frac{25}{4}\pi$$ which kind off makes no sense.

Comment: Your work looks correct and I got the [same value](https://bit.ly/3235QuJ); why don't you think it makes sense?

Comment: @ryang My bad. I overlooked that $x,y,z\leq 0$. I would have expected something positive. I still do not see how we get the boundaries for $\varphi$ and $\theta$. Can you help me out?

Comment: Yes the integral is nonpositive since $f$ is always nonpositive in the region of interest. In spherical coordinates, a partial/whole sphere's limits of integration are all constants. The bounds given in your answer are all correct since they describe the part of the sphere that is in the octant whose Cartesian coordinates are nonpositive. In the above Wolframalpha link (where $t$ and $w$ stand for $θ$ and $φ,$ respectively), I'd deliberately used a contrasting range for $\theta,\;(-\pi,\pi]$ instead of $[0,2\pi).$ I will upvote your answer.

Comment: @ryang Yes, of course! Now I see why the boundaries have to be that way. Thank you very much for your comments!